# java Collections.binarySearch() returning -2

Tags: java, sorting, collections, binary-tree

I have a text file which contains student information. I sort this information using the comparator class which implements the `comparator` interface.This sorts fine fine when calling `Collection.Sort();`

I then use the `comparator` in the `binarySearch()` method.  I have an int index that returns the index of the binary search. after debugging it seems that the `binarySearch()` isnt sorting the data properly because I get an index of 0 for 501 which is correct, an index of 1 for 503 which is incorrect and an index of -2 for 502. Is the `binarySearch` not using the comparator apppropriately and thus not sorting the data appropriately as its returning the data in its original form.

```
 =================================================
    First Name: Mark
    Last Name: Evans
    Registration: 501

    Subject: Maths
    Assignment: 1
    Homewok Mark: 70
    Exam Mark: 80

    Assignment: 2
    Homewok Mark: 70
    Exam Mark: 40

    Subject: English
    Assignment: 1
    Homewok Mark: 40
    Exam Mark: 50

    Assignment: 2
    Homewok Mark: 60
    Exam Mark: 70

    Subject: Science
    Assignment: 1
    Homewok Mark: 50
    Exam Mark: 60

    Assignment: 2
    Homewok Mark: 80
    Exam Mark: 45

    Assignment: 3
    Homewok Mark: 67
    Exam Mark: 47

    Assignment: 4
    Homewok Mark: 38
    Exam Mark: 57

    =================================================
    First Name: Linda
    Last Name: Evans
    Registration: 503

    Subject: Maths
    Assignment: 1
    Homewok Mark: 50
    Exam Mark: 60

    Assignment: 2
    Homewok Mark: 70
    Exam Mark: 50

    =================================================
    First Name: Joseph
    Last Name: Evanw
    Registration: 502

    Subject: English
    Assignment: 1
    Homewok Mark: 40
    Exam Mark: 50
```

I have a comparator class that works fine and sorts the data appropriately.

```
public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {

        int registrationNumber1 = s1.getRegistrationNumber();
        int registrationNumber12 = s2.getRegistrationNumber();

        return registrationNumber1 - registrationNumber12;
    }

}


public void searchStudentByName() {

        int number = 503;
        int subjectNumber = 1;

        int index = Collections.binarySearch(studentList, new Student(number),
                new StudentComparator());
        for (int i = 0; studentList.size() > i; i++) {
            if (i == index) {

                System.out.print(studentList.get(i));

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the list sorted at the time you call `binarySearch()`?

Comment: What is the type of `studentList`?  In any event, `binarySearch` doesn't work at all unless the list you're search is already sorted.  Otherwise you will just get garbage.  See the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T)).

Comment: If you're sorting it beforehand, could you show us the code you're using to sort it, to make sure you're using the correct sort?  (Also, you might want to add something that prints out all the registration numbers from `studentList` before you do the `binarySearch`, just to make sure it's sorted.)

Comment: lol thanks @Bohemian I thought the comparator did all the sorting x-X

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To perform a binary search, the collection must already be sorted.  You are expecting `binarySearch` to sort it for you, but it doesn't sort it.  It takes advantage of the assumption that it's already sorted.  The [Javadocs for `Collections.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T,%20java.util.Comparator)) state:

> Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm. The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the specified comparator (as by the sort(List, Comparator) method), prior to making this call. If it is not sorted, the results are undefined.

Add a call to `Collections.sort` before attempting a binary search.

```
StudentComparator sc = new StudentComparator();
Collections.sort(studentList, sc);
```

Then you can call `Collections.binarySearch`.

Comment: Yup, I was I was just lazy and didn't bother to read the API :).